# Is this a MySQL JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, rdbms, star-schema

```
SELECT
     dim_date.date, dim_locations.city, fact_numbers.metric
FROM
     dim_date, fact_numbers
WHERE
     dim_date.id = fact_numbers.fk_dim_date_id
AND
     dim_locations.city = "Toronto"
AND
     dim_date.date = 2010-04-13;
```

Since I'm not using the `JOIN` command, I'm wondering if this is indeed a `JOIN` (and if not, what to call it)?

This is for a dimensional model by the way which is using surrogate and primary keys to match up details

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11180050/1291428; ansi join vs implicit joins

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing that link; it looks as though it's advised to use explicit joins rather than implicit

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is joining the tables together so it will provide related information from all of the tables.

The one major downfall of linking tables via `WHERE` instead of `JOIN` is not being able to use `LEFT`,  `RIGHT`, and `Full` to show records from one table even if missing in the other.

However, your SQL statement is invalid.  You are not linking `dim_locations` to either of the other tables and it is missing in the `FROM` clause.

Your query using an `INNER JOIN` which is comparable to your `WHERE` clause may look something like the following:

```
SELECT DD.date, DL.city, FN.metric
FROM dim_date AS DD
  JOIN fact_numbers AS FN ON DD.id = FN.fk_dim_date_id
  JOIN dim_locations AS DL ON DL.id = FN.fk_dim_locations_id
WHERE DL.city = 'Toronto'
AND DD.date = 2010-04-13
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, it is joining tables. It is called non-ANSI JOIN syntax when join clause is not used explicitly. And when join clause is used, it is ANSI JOIN

Comment: Just curious, how is the term "ANSI" pronounced? Do people read it as A N S I join or "an-c"?

Comment: the second one what I pronounce. And my native language is not English.

Answer (score 1):

If you reference two different tables in a where clause and compare their referential IDs, then yes, it acts the same as a `JOIN`.

Note however that this can be very inefficient if the optimizer doesn't optimize it properly see: [Is there something wrong with joins that don't use the JOIN keyword in SQL or MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128965/is-there-something-wrong-with-joins-that-dont-use-the-join-keyword-in-sql-or-my) and [INNER JOIN keywords | with and without using them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652151/inner-join-keywords-with-and-without-using-them)