# Why we need LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

As we all know about LEFT, RIGHT JOIN and other JOIN in SQL to join different table as per condition into one.

But my Question is that why we need LEFT or RIGHT JOIN as we can get the same output by using one of that?

Why not use only LEFT or RIGHT JOIN to get an appropriate answer.

Comment: Yes. Just use LEFT JOIN.

Comment: If you have more than one table involved the two aren't so easily interchangable though it is always possible to rearrange LOJ to ROJ and vice versa.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I agree with your vote, but I think [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7313507/562459) is the better one, especially for the current question.

Comment: This article gives a pretty good explanation: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/