# What are the parentheses doing in this SQL Statement in the FROM CLAUSE (TSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

What are the parentheses on lines 5 and 11 for?

```
 1    SELECT
 2        s.name, s.ShirtDescription, c.Color, 
 3        z.Size, i.AvailableQTY, i.UnitPrice 
 4    FROM 
 5       (    
 6          test.ShirtInventory i
 7          join test.Colors c ON
 8              i.ColorID = c.id 
 9          join test.Shirts s ON
10              i.ShirtID = s.ID
11       )
12    JOIN test.Sizes z ON 
13       i.SizeID = z.ID 
14    WHERE .....
```

I've never seen parentheses used this way in the FROM Clause. This isn't a sub query, and it's not scoping the the table and the joins. You can see where I reference i.SizeID outside the parentheses. When I first saw it, I thought it might be a way to "hint" to SQL Server how you wanted the data to be fetched, but nothing changes in the execution plan when you remove the parens.

Look forward to your replies.
edit: got the lines wrong

Comment: Was this from a code generator?  That would explain useless parentheses

Comment: @Hogan not sure, the code is from a 3rd party in an interface application. I've got to modify the SQL and wanted to make sure I wasn't breaking something I didn't understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing in this case as inner joins are associative and commutative.

In general you can change the virtual tables that participate in joins by moving the position of the `on` clause and this can have optional parentheses applied also to hopefully make things clearer.

So [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7313507/73226) you could have

```
SELECT P.PersonName,
       Pt.PetName,
       Pa.AccessoryName
FROM   Persons P
       LEFT JOIN Pets Pt
                  INNER JOIN PetAccessories Pa
                    ON Pt.PetName = Pa.PetName
         ON P.PersonName = Pt.PersonName;
```

Which optionally might also be written

```
SELECT P.PersonName,
       Pt.PetName,
       Pa.AccessoryName
FROM   Persons P
       LEFT JOIN (Pets Pt
                  INNER JOIN PetAccessories Pa
                    ON Pt.PetName = Pa.PetName)
         ON P.PersonName = Pt.PersonName;
```

Comment: or another way to put it is -- These parentheses are doing the default, if they were moved then that might cause a change.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the clarification. Thinking back, I've seen parens used with outer Joins in the past as you mentioned. the more I think about the circumstances surrounding this mess, The more I think @Hogan might be on to something with his thought about an automated scripting tool being in the mix somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It is a sub query, its treating everything within the parenthesis as the base table. It doesn't look necessary in this instance though as it's just then joining to the final table anyway

Comment: That's not a derived table.  Derived table would require a full Select statement inside the parenthesis.  These parenthesis do nothing.  Maybe they were left over from a time when there was a full Select statement inside the parenthesis.

Comment: Yep, didn't notice that. you're totally correct, thanks for fixing that one.

Comment: when I first saw this, I was thinking the same thing, Rich. I wasn't until I noticed the subsequent JOINS referring back to tables inside the parens that I knew it wasn't a subquery, thanks for the input.