# why do i need left outer join if i have right outer join?

Tags: sql, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When or why would you use a right outer join instead of left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436345/when-or-why-would-you-use-a-right-outer-join-instead-of-left)

What ever the functionality i get with left outer join  i can get it by interchanging table names.Then, what is the need for having two outer joins ( left and right) ? If there is any specific need can some body explain with an example ?

Comment: Why go east when I can go west? I'll eventually get there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do we use >= when < does the same thing?

Mostly it's a convenience thing.

Answer (score 1):

They're the same thing, use whichever makes more sense to your mind when reading the query.