# Usage of [Right] .. JOIN in practice

Tags: sql

This question is related to:

- [When or why would you use a right outer join instead of left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436345/when-or-why-would-you-use-a-right-outer-join-instead-of-left)
- [what is the use of right join exactly as we can get the same result from left join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032819/what-is-the-use-of-right-join-exactly-as-we-can-get-the-same-result-from-left-jo)

---

I was wondering if **in practice** anyone has written or come across the usage of a `RIGHT JOIN` that is useful? If so, what was the scenario? I have not really myself (outside of seeing examples of "look at this RIGHT join"), so was wondering if this is actually used in practice, and if so, what was the context?

Comment: People tend to avoid `RIGHT JOIN`, because they are somehow counter-intuitive (at least for people that read from left to right!). But bottom line that's more a matter of taste, which, to me, qualifies the question as opinion-based.

Comment: @GMB . . . It is not just a matter of taste.  SQL parses from left-to-right and `A LEFT JOIN B LEFT JOIN C` can be subtly different from `C RIGHT JOIN B RIGHT JOIN A` depending on the conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a situation where I need a lateral join to get the `join` key for a column (say because the values are stored in an array).  Then I want to outer join to a fixed list of codes, say to count them.  I could write this as:

```
select c.code, count(u.code)
from codes c left join
     (t cross join lateral
      unnest(codes) u(code)
     )
     on c.code = u.code;
```

Or by using a `right join`:

```
select c.code, count(u.code)
from t cross join lateral
     unnest(codes) u(code) right join
     codes c
     on c.code = u.code;
```

I *still* prefer the `left join` version, but some might reasonably prefer avoiding parentheses in the `from` clause.

If you have only two tables in the `from` clause, `left join` and `right join` are interchangeable; this is not always true when there are more than two tables.  I'm not sure if reading direction for the alphabet would affect which outer join someone prefers.  I would hypothesize that the underlying grammar of the user's native language might have an effect, perhaps languages where the object precedes the subject; such languages are rather rare, though, and not among the more commonly spoken languages.

Comment: also, what is a `lateral join` ? i've never seen that before -- what rdbms?

Comment: @David542 . . . Lateral joins are part of the SQL standard, although the syntax varies (SQL Server uses `cross apply`, for instance).  Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, the most recent version of MySQL, PrestoDB, and Snowflake (and perhaps others) support them.

Comment: is this the official SQL standard? https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9695959099/toc.pdf Or is there another site you can link to that contains the SQL standard?

Answer (score 0):

actually there's nothing specific different practice between `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` but **clause sentence arrangement**. back in definition of SQL it is just statement arrangement for order command to your DBMS.

if you use `RIGHT JOIN` clause, the data will served more inclined to table on the **Right** (which is mentioned after that **JOIN** clause), using `LEFT JOIN` makes the opposites from `RIGHT JOIN`