# Right Outer Join Significance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Though we can achieve the same result when we put right table in left and use left outer join. Then what is the significance of Right Outer Join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same reason we have less than and greater than symbols. It helps with clarity and completeness.

Answer (score 0):

This was already asked in [When or why would you use a right outer join instead of left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436345/when-or-why-would-you-use-a-right-outer-join-instead-of-left) 
Basically it is the same but it makes your code a bit more self-documenting