# Find ID which doesn't exist from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am studying SQL and I am not sure which is the way to filtering data.

For example, there I have two tables:

`Reference_OrderTable`:

- OrderID
- Item
- Price

`OrderTable`:

- OrderID
- Item
- Price

- `Reference_Ordertable`: this table has all the type of orders.
- `OrderTable`: this is the actual order table, we store by customer's orders.

I am looking for missing `orderID` in `OrderTable`.

For example:

Reference_Ordertable:

OrderID: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

OrderTable:

OrderID: 1, 3, 4, 5, 7

I would like to find the missing part such as `OrderID`: 2, 6, 8 because `OrderTable` is missing 2,6,8 if we compare with `Reference_Ordertable`.

I was thinking to use Right Join method. However, Right Join contains common data and it is not searching missing part. How can we filter missing data from another table?

Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, while you could use an outer join here, I'd recommend a LEFT JOIN (not RIGHT).  Technically either works, but LEFT JOINs are more common.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436345/when-or-why-would-you-use-a-right-outer-join-instead-of-left

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below.

Using EXCEPT

```
select OrderID from reference_OrderTable
EXCEPT
select OrderID from OrderTable
```

using join

```
select r.OrderID from reference_OrderTable r 
LEFT JOIN OrderTable o ON o.OrderID = r.OrderID
WHERE o.OrderID IS NULL
```

using sub queries

```
select OrderID from reference_OrderTable
where OrderID NOT IN (select OrderID from OrderTable)
```

Comment: Good list.  There's also `WHERE NOT EXISTS (....)`.  BTW, I think the they're looking for orders missing from `OrdersTable`, rather than the other way around.

Comment: Thanks!! I kept searching Join method. I think, "Except" and "NOT IN" can be simpler. Good to learn EXCEPT and NOT IN. Thanks!

Comment: @NBB - They each have slight differences in behavior and pros/cons, so read up on them. Also, compare query execution plans to select the best option for your specific query.